# Get ddl type sqls from Snowflake History

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am interested in getting ddl executed on Snowflake database schemas, this ddl is like create / alter type SQL statements.Is there is any way to capture this metadata using Snowflake.Account_Usage schema or any other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the `snowflake` shared database then you can use the `snowflake.account_usage.query_history` view to do this. It has a column called `query_type` which shows you what type of query was run. Here is an example:

```sql
-- Run some sample queries
create or replace database sample_database;
create or replace table sample_database.public.test_table (col1 varchar);
alter table sample_database.public.test_table add column col2 varchar;
insert overwrite into sample_database.public.test_table values ('row 1 col 1', 'row 1 col 2'), ('row 2 col 1', 'row 2 col 2');


-- Use the snowflake.account_usage.query_history view to see what the query types were
select 
    query_text, 
    database_name, 
    schema_name, 
    query_type
from snowflake.account_usage.query_history 
where database_name = 'SAMPLE_DATABASE' order by start_time;

-- results
+------------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------+------------------------+
|                QUERY_TEXT                |  DATABASE_NAME  | SCHEMA_NAME |       QUERY_TYPE       |
+------------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------+------------------------+
| create or replace table sample_databa... | SAMPLE_DATABASE | PUBLIC      | CREATE_TABLE           |
| alter table sample_database.public.te... | SAMPLE_DATABASE | PUBLIC      | ALTER_TABLE_ADD_COLUMN |
| insert overwrite into sample_database... | SAMPLE_DATABASE | PUBLIC      | INSERT                 |
| select * from snowflake.account_usage... | SAMPLE_DATABASE | PUBLIC      | SELECT                 |
+------------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------+------------------------+
```

Note that the `account_usage` views [have a slight delay](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#account-usage-views) so your queries may not show up immediately. The `query_history` view, in particular, as an approximate latency of 45 minutes according to the documentation I just linked to.

An alternative method would be to use the [QUERY_HISTORY, QUERY_HISTORY_BY_*](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html#query-history-query-history-by) table functions which don't have a delay to my knowledge. Here is an example of that:

```sql
-- Run some sample queries
create or replace database sample_database;
create or replace table sample_database.public.test_table (col1 varchar);
alter table sample_database.public.test_table add column col2 varchar;
insert overwrite into sample_database.public.test_table values ('row 1 col 1', 'row 1 col 2'), ('row 2 col 1', 'row 2 col 2');

-- Use the table functions to see the history and view the query types run in the last hour
select 
    query_text, 
    database_name, 
    schema_name, 
    query_type
from table(information_schema.query_history(dateadd('hours',-1,current_timestamp()),current_timestamp()))
where database_name = 'SAMPLE_DATABASE'
order by start_time;

-- results
+------------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------+------------------------+
|                QUERY_TEXT                |  DATABASE_NAME  | SCHEMA_NAME |       QUERY_TYPE       |
+------------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------+------------------------+
| create or replace table sample_databa... | SAMPLE_DATABASE | PUBLIC      | CREATE_TABLE           |
| alter table sample_database.public.te... | SAMPLE_DATABASE | PUBLIC      | ALTER_TABLE_ADD_COLUMN |
| insert overwrite into sample_database... | SAMPLE_DATABASE | PUBLIC      | INSERT                 |
| select * from snowflake.account_usage... | SAMPLE_DATABASE | PUBLIC      | SELECT                 |
+------------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: To get only DDL change statements executed, you can add to @SimonD answer a filter on the QUERY_TYPE using something like QUERY_TYPE in ('ALTER_TABLE', 'CREATE_TABLE'.... You can get a list doing DISTINCT on that column. If you've been using Snowflake a while most or all DML types should be in the distinct list.

Comment: Thanks Simon and Greg