# Snowflake tracker changes by which user

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake I want to be able to see which objects have been modified by which users.

In the Snowflake documentation it states a stream can be created to track object changes but does not mention whether this includes tracker the user who made the changes.

Can someone confirm if user changes are tracked?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "object in snowflake" means tables or all objects created using create statements? Stream objects are created on the top of table to perform CDC operations. For table, you can use table history command to see the changes, however I don't think it is directly possible to capture the user changes.

Answer (score 2):

Tracking the actual changes to objects with users who did it, is not a supported feature in Snowflake at the moment.

However, there can be different alternatives to extract what has happened to a given object.
There is an example of that here [Get ddl type sqls from Snowflake History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65275620/get-ddl-type-sqls-from-snowflake-history)

The above linked example only shows four columns - there is also the possibility of retrieving the USER who issued the query, the role etc. from the same query.

Regarding [STREAMS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams.html): A STREAM in Snowflake only tracks the changes to the data, not who made the changes or what DDL changes has happened to a table.

Hope that clarifies things for you.